# Ui automatorviewer is not displaying element of a floating menu if it is align above of any recycler view

Tags: appium-android

I want to click on one of the floating buttons(the pink colour buttons). But the Uiautomatorviewer is not showing the element location of any buttons of "floating menu" on the screen.  Could anyone please help me out on this.[All the channel showing is a recycler view and all the pink colour button is floating menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNcfX.png)

Comment: is the app published or in git hub?

Comment: No Alin, neither it is published nor is in git hub. Its still in working mode. Do you have any idea of how to get/find the elementID of floating menu.